# Next.jsのApp Routerにおいて、layout.tsx内でデザインを定義し、グローバルに適用する方法

Tags: typescript, next.js

[ src/app/layout.tsx ]

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import React from 'react'; // Reactをインポート

const Container = styled.div`
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fd, #4e54c8);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
`;

interface LayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
  return <Container>{children}</Container>;
}
```

上記の様にlayout.tsxを書き換え、「npm run dev」を実行した所、

```
const Container = styled.div`
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fd, #4e54c8);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
`;
```

という様に定義したスタイルが背景として設定されず、白い背景のままでした。
どの様にすれば、正しく背景が設定されるのでしょうか？

ご回答お待ちしております。